# loadJson without jquery mozzila

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I need get json page data without jquery. My code works on chrome and IE, but doesn't work on mozzila. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadJSON(path, success, error){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (success)
                    success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                if (error)
                    error(xhr);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", path, true);
    xhr.send();
}

loadJSON(
    'https://freegeoip.net/json/',
    function(data) { alert(data.ip); },
    function(xhr) { alert("BAD"); }
); 

</script>
```

Comment: The company name is "Mozilla" — One z and two ls — but the name of the browser is "Firefox". (Unless you are talking about the Mozilla Suite … which I really hope you aren't).

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very poor problem statement. Do some basic debugging. Figure out where it fails. Look at the Console and the Network tab in the developer tools. Quote error messages. Quote HTTP responses (highlighting where they are different in Internet Explorer).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anyway. The code works fine when I test it in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

it shows alert("bad") on firefox, 
but on chrome shows alert ip